# How to delegate permission to generate SAS to 3rd party in Azure

Tags: azure, permissions

I know nothing about azure. Experienced with AWS and GCP. What I've been tasked to do is set up a system where customers of ours have data in Azure storage containers (blobs), which are not public. The idea is that we would want to be able to serve content from our customers storage container to OUR customers using a SAS link that expires in a short period of time (say, a few seconds).

I'm finding the docs highly confusing and am just hoping I can get a pointer in the correct direction. Looking at the Ruby api, it looks like I need to supply an account name and an access secret to generate a SAS. So, presumably our customer would have to provide that to us. How would they create that account/key with minimal permissions so that all we can do is create the SAS link and serve it to our customers?

I'm reading all kinds of things about Active Directory and RBAC and SAS and Service Principles and all this stuff, but not sure how it fits together. I've implemented something similar in AWS, where the customer just creates an IAM user with GetObject permission on the bucket, they give us the key/secret, and we use it to generate a signed url. But azure is a whole different beast.